# MariaDB "ON UPDATE CASCADE" CONSTRAINT not working as expected?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, constraints, hierarchical-data

I was expecting that a `ON UPDATE CASCADE` constraint would let me update value of the referenced foreign key and would cascade it to it's referee (as it does in PostgreSQL), but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Am I missing something ?

*Here using MariaDB 10.3.29-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1*

```sql
CREATE TABLE category (
  id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  slug varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  content longtext NOT NULL,
  created_at datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  updated_at datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_category_parent_id FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES category (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


INSERT INTO `category` (`id`, `parent_id`, `slug`, `title`, `content`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, NULL, 'non-classe', 'Non Classé', '', '2021-05-30 16:46:52', NULL),
(2, NULL, 'cours', 'Cours', '', '2021-05-30 16:47:38', NULL),
(3, 2, 'mysql', 'MySQL', '', '2021-05-30 16:48:18', NULL),
(4, 3, 'initiation-mysql', 'Cours initiation MySQL', '', '2021-05-30 16:49:09', NULL);

UPDATE category SET id = 12 WHERE id = 2;
-- ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cours_cms`.`category`, CONSTRAINT `fk_category_parent_id` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Comment: Id 3 wants to keep 2 as parent.

Comment: @jarlh but the ON UPDATE CASCADE is there so that id:3 parent_id updates in cascade... that is what it's there for! (and that is how it works in PostgreSQL or Oracle)

Comment: Oops, I didn't read carefully enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the comment on this page:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/foreign-keys/

> If ON UPDATE CASCADE recurses to update the same table it has previously updated during the cascade, it acts like RESTRICT. This means that you cannot use self-referential ON UPDATE CASCADE operations. This is to prevent infinite loops resulting from cascaded updates.

In other words, ON UPDATE CASCADE does not work if it's a hierarchical-data kind of table.

Comment: I think this answers my question... MySQL partially implementing concepts drives me nuts!

Comment: Why aren't you using PostgreSQL then?

Comment: Postgres has its own percs

Comment: @BillKarwin because I'm asked to do a class on MySQL :'(

Comment: @nbk but PostgreSQL has never deceived me like mysql does every day

Comment: Postgres has too many functions like php has, nobody knows exactly, what is behind all or how to find it, if you chekc the questions for postgres, they even worse than the ones for Mysql

Answer (score 0):

just confirming this works in PostgreSQL without 'infinite loops'

```sql
CREATE TABLE category (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id int DEFAULT NULL,
  slug varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  content text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_category_parent_id FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES category (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO category (id, parent_id, slug, title, content) VALUES
(1, NULL, 'non-classe', 'Non Classé', ''),
(2, NULL, 'cours', 'Cours', ''),
(3, 2, 'mysql', 'MySQL', ''),
(4, 3, 'initiation-mysql', 'Cours initiation MySQL', '');

UPDATE category SET id=12 WHERE id=2;

SELECT * FROM category;
 id | parent_id |       slug       |         title          | content 
----+-----------+------------------+------------------------+---------
  1 |           | non-classe       | Non Classé             | 
  4 |         3 | initiation-mysql | Cours initiation MySQL | 
 12 |           | cours            | Cours                  | 
  3 |        12 | mysql            | MySQL                  |
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved my issue in laravel code:

I changed this

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade̥');
```

to this:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->cascadeOnUpdate()->cascadeOnDelete();
```